# Double Render Error rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm tyring ot create a custom method in my controller

So far it looks like this

```
 def url
    require 'json'
    url = url appears here
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.css(".ticket-price .h4").each do |t|
      json = t.text
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render :json => {:seatname => json}}
      end
    end
  end
```

However when i run this i get this error

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
```

I can't see where the its being called twice? my guess however is that because its inside the each statement. What would be the best way to display the two seat names that come back in json so that it looks like this:

```
"seatname": "seat1",
"seatname": "seat2"
```

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Move the `respond_to` block out of the loop

Comment: Tried this, Get an error, that it couldnt find json, Changed the @json and get only the last seat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def url
    require 'json'
    url = url appears here
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    // Constructing an array of hash
    response_hash = doc.css(".ticket-price .h4").map{ |t| {seatname: t.text} }

    respond_to do |format|
       format.json  { render :json => response_hash }
    end
end
```

Like Max mentioned, in your code `respond_to` gets called for every matching element. Instead you can construct an array of hash, and then render that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
def url
   require 'json'
   url = url appears here
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

   response_hash = doc.css(".ticket-price .h4").map { |t| ["seatname", t.text] }.to_h

   respond_to do |format|
     format.json  { render :json => response_hash }
   end
 end
```

In your current code, the `respond_to` block is being called once for each matching element in the return value of `doc.css(...)`, which is causing the `DoubleRenderError`. To fix that, you need to separate constructing your response data from actually sending it. Does that help?

Comment: This nearly works, There are two seats and this is returning the last seat